# What does $0 mean in an HTML tag?

Tags: html

```
<hr size="3" noshade $ 0>
```

I'm learning the basics of HTML through an online course, and recently I was taught the `<hr>` tag.

I understood the purpose of the `<hr>` tag, and the use of its attribute `size` - but what does the `$0` mean in it? What function is it performing there?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you can add the code you have written with the hr tag, it will be easier for others to see what the problem might be.

Comment: The code was <hr size="3" noshade $0>

Comment: The second code <hr $0>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$0` symbol is not part of HTML, it appears in the DOM Inspector to indicate the currently selected element.

[The `$0` variable](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities), when typed in the Console, will be a reference to that element which you can use for ad-hoc JS.

Comment: It will be kind if you explain it deeply because I'm a new person in this field so can't understand

Comment: There's nothing more to it. It's just that.

Comment: Very kind of you to help me I just understood it.